# React on rails not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am trying to render my react component on my ruby on rails app. There is no error but the page renders nothing. I suspect if the tutorial is outdated or if failed to asked me to import some stuff.

I followed closely to this site: https://medium.com/quick-code/simple-rails-crud-app-with-react-frontend-using-react-rails-gem-b708b89a9419

This is probably the most critical part of the tutorial.

```
Let’s return to config/routes.rb for a second and add our Home index page to be the root:

root to: 'home#index'

Now all our index page need is a corresponding view. Create a new ‘home’ folder inside app/views and add index.html.erb file to it:

app/views/home/index.html.erb

This file will only contain one line that takes advantage of react_component view helper that comes with ‘react-rails’ gem. It’s not going to work right now, but it all will make sense in a moment.

<%= react_component 'Main' %>

Creating our first React Component
Create a file named app/assets/javascripts/components/_main.js.jsx
We are going to follow the usual syntax for creating a stateless/presentational React Component that we will call Main:

const Main = (props) => {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Fruits are great!</h1>
      </div>
    )
}
Head to localhost:3000 in the browser and see for yourself that our first Component was loaded on the page. Pretty cool!
```

I tried to include code like

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

but nothing renders too.
When trying to debug, I tried not to deviate from the tutorial as I am still new and hope to learn from one source at a time to prevent conflicting and different methods.

Comment: Please clear the console and reload the page once, then copy and paste the server console output here. It will help.